# Will iCloud back it up?

Tags: ipod-touch

I recently installed iCloud into my iPod touch 4th generation. I'm thinking about resetting my iPod because of some problems I've been having lately. Will iCloud back up/save all my info, apps, etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will save your info and redownload your apps for you, but it will also bring back any software issues you were trying to get rid of. What info were you most concerned with?